# Why is GHC contradicting itself when using a Coercible constraint?

Tags: haskell, ghc, coercion, type-families

Why is GHC inferring unification from coercibility of associated data, and why is it contradicting its own checked type signature to do so?

### The problem

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE ExplicitForAll #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ConstraintKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RecordWildCards #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

module Lib
    ( 
    ) where

import Data.Coerce

class Foo a where
  data Bar a

data Baz a = Baz
  { foo :: a
  , bar :: Bar a
  }

type BarSame a b = (Coercible (Bar a) (Bar b), Coercible (Bar b) (Bar a))

withBaz :: forall a b. BarSame a b => (a -> b) -> Baz a -> Baz b
withBaz f Baz{..} = Baz
  { foo = f foo
  , bar = coerce bar
  }
```

This is all well and good - GHC will happily compile this code, and is confident that `withBaz` has the declared signature.

Now, let's try to use it!

```hs
instance (Foo a) => Foo (Maybe a) where
  data Bar (Maybe a) = MabyeBar (Bar a)

toMaybeBaz :: Baz a -> Baz (Maybe a)
toMaybeBaz = withBaz Just
```

*This* gives an error - but a really weird one:

```
withBaz Just
^^^^^^^^^^^^
cannot construct the infinite type: a ~ Maybe a
```

Indeed, if I go into GHCi, and ask it to give me the type of `withBaz`:

```
ghc>:t withBaz
withBaz :: (b -> b) -> Baz b -> Baz b
```

That's not the signature I gave it.

#### Coercibility

I suspect that GHC is treating the type arguments of `withBaz` as though they have to unify, because it's inferring `Coercible a b` from `Coercible (Bar a) (Bar b)`. But because it's a data family, they don't even need to be `Coercible` - certainly  not unifiable.

## Update!

The following change fixes the compilation:

```hs
instance (Foo a) => Foo (Maybe a) where
  newtype Bar (Maybe a) = MabyeBar (Bar a)
```

That is - declare the data family as a `newtype`, instead of a `data`. This seems consistent with GHC's treatment of `Coercible` in the language in general, in that

```hs
data Id a = Id a
```

will *not* cause a `Coercible` instance to be generated - even though it should definitely be coercible to `a`. With the above declaration, this will error:

```hs
wrapId :: a -> Id a
wrapId = coerce
```

But with a `newtype` declaration:

```hs
newtype Id a = Id a
```

then the `Coercible` instance exists, and `wrapId` compiles.

Comment: Very weird. I'm tempted to say this looks like plainly a bug in the typechecker.

Comment: First off, you can simplify your example code just by pointing out that the function `test :: forall a b. (Coercible (Bar a) (Bar b)) => Bar a -> Bar b` with implementation `test = coerce` ends up with the type `test :: Bar b -> Bar b` in GHCi.  That said, can you provide an example of _using_ `withBaz` at any actually concrete type?  For instance, for `toMaybeBaz`, what type do you have in mind that is coercible to `MabyeBar (Bar a)`?

Comment: "what type do you have in mind that is coercible to `MabyeBar (Bar a)`?" - `Bar a`, which `Bar (Maybe a)` is a wrapper around. They clearly have the same representation in memory, so they should be coercible.

Comment: I've added an update, since @DDub 's comment inspired me to look back over some older code that *did* use `coerce` in this way, and I found that it had a `newtype` declaration for the associated data family, rather than a `data` one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe @dfeuer's since-deleted comment about lack of "role" support for type/data families provides the answer.

For a top-level, `data`-defined parametrized type:

```
data Foo a = ...
```

the coercibility of types `Foo a` and `Foo b` depends on the role of the parameter `a`.  In particular, if `a`s role is *nominal*, then `Foo a` and `Foo b` are coercible if and only if `a` and `b` are precisely the same type.

So, in the program:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RoleAnnotations #-}

import Data.Coerce

type role Foo nominal
data Foo a = Foo

foo :: (Coercible (Foo a) (Foo b)) => a -> b
foo = undefined
```

because of the `nominal` role of the parameter `a` in `Foo a`, the type of `foo` is actually simplified to `b -> b`:

```
λ> :t foo
foo :: b -> b
```

If the role annotation is changed from `nominal` to `representational`, the type is simplified to `Coercible a b => a -> b`, and if the role is changed to `phantom` (the default for this particular declaration of `Foo`, as `a` does not appear on the right-hand side), the type is simplified to `a -> b`.  This is all as expected and corresponds to the definition of each of these roles.

Note that if you replaced the declaration of `Foo` with:

```
data Foo a = Foo a
```

then the `phantom` role would not longer be permitted, but the inferred types for `foo` under the other two roles would be exactly as before.

However, there's an important difference if you switch from a `data` to a `newtype`. With:

```
newtype Foo a = Foo a
```

you'd discover that even with `type role Foo nominal`, the inferred type for `foo` would be `Coercible b a => a -> b` instead of `b -> b`.  That's because the algorithm for type-safe coercions handles `newtype`s differently than "equivalent" `data` types, as you've noted in your question -- they are always immediately coercible through unwrapping whenever the constructor is in scope, regardless of the role of the type parameter.

So, with all that being said, your experience with associated data families is consistent with the role of the family's type parameter being set to `nominal`. Though I couldn't find it documented in the GHC manual, this appears to be as-designed behavior, and there's [an open ticket](https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/-/issues/8177) that acknowledges all data/type families have all parameters assigned `nominal` role and proposes relaxing this restriction, and @dfeuer actually has a [detailed proposal](https://github.com/ghc-proposals/ghc-proposals/pull/373/commits) from this past October.

Comment: SPJ may have a ticket. I have [a proposal](https://github.com/ghc-proposals/ghc-proposals/pull/373). I rather unthinkingly deleted the comment Thurs answer is based on...  Oooops.

Comment: "`newtypes` ... are always immediately coercible through unwrapping ... regardless of the role of the type parameter" - this is an interesting choice of design. Do you know where it comes from? I feel like, if you explicitly write `type role MyNewType nominal`, that GHC would ignore your specification seems absolutely bonkers.

Comment: It may help to read [the paper](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/uploads/prod/2018/05/coercible-JFP.pdf).  Basically, roles govern coercions between types with the same type constructor and different parametrizations:  e.g., can `MyNewType FirstType` be coerced to `MyNewType SecondType`.  In contrast, coercions from a `newtype` to its wrapped value (e.g., given `newtype MyNewType a = MyNewType a`, coercing `MyNewType a` to `a`) are governed by having the constructor in scope (with the rationale that it's just a zero-cost alternative to `case x of MyNewtype y -> y`).

Comment: If you want roles to matter with `newtype`s, arrange to have the constructor out-of-scope, by hiding it in a module, for example.